# Hide address and toolbar in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm using Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m

I would like to know if there is a way to hide the address bar and toolbar?
The flag Compact Navigation seems to have been removed.

Is there maybe a solution to do this using Chrome Apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but chrome extensions can't change the ui in any way(other than adding and changing their own icons).  The closest you could get to doing this is by full-screening the browser:

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, { state: "fullscreen" })
```

look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update

chrome apps default start with no addressbar.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that an extension can create separate windows that don't have addressbar and toolbar - popups and panels - via `chrome.window.create`, however such windows can't have tabs.

Comment: doing this can I also have the feature of using several tabs to navigate. If I click on a link it opens up on a new tab for instance ?

Comment: yes, but the user won't be able to change to another tab without using keyboard shortcuts.  links will redirect you just fine.